# How to use front camera in tensorflow object detection api on android demo

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera, object-detection

I want to use the front camera in the android demo of tensorflow , what should i change in the code cause im not really familiar with android.

This is the code i changed but didn't solve the problem

```java
private String chooseCamera() {
    final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      for (final String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
        final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
        final Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
          continue;
        }

        final StreamConfigurationMap map =
            characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        if (map == null) {
          continue;
        }

        // Fallback to camera1 API for internal cameras that don't have full support.
        // This should help with legacy situations where using the camera2 API causes
        // distorted or otherwise broken previews.
        useCamera2API = (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL)
            || isHardwareLevelSupported(characteristics, 
                                        CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL);
        LOGGER.i("Camera API lv2?: %s", useCamera2API);
        return cameraId;
      }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Not allowed to access camera");
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Originally it was Lens_Facing_Back , i made it Lens_Facing_Front

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: check the post again i added wht i have done so far.

Comment: You posetd code that does not change the camera choice, it's exactly same as [the tensorflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/CameraActivity.java#L325).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. There is a function called `getCameraID()` in `legacyCameraConnectionFragment`. Open its implementation and change 
`CAMERA_FACING_BACK` to `CAMERA_FACING_FRONT`.